# How can the aperture value written in Exif be larger than the nominal limit of the lens?

Tags: aperture, metadata

A photo shot with an 1:1.8 lens contains the following exif data:

```
ApertureValue: 1695994/1000000  
MaxApertureValue: 16/10
```

How is this possible? Both values are <1.8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are confused because `ApertureValue` and `MaxApertureValue` are APEX values, not f-stops.

An f-number of 1.8 is equivalent to an APEX aperture value of about 1.695994. (The formula is \$\mathrm{A_v} = \log_2{\mathrm{A}^2},\$ where \$\mathrm{A_v}\$ is `ApertureValue` and \$\mathrm{A}\$ is f-number. See
[the Wikipedia APEX system page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system) for a full explanation.)

Some Exif readers (like ExifTool) convert these to f-stops for the user, but others do not.

Comment: Woah! I can't believe I didn't realize that. That's crazy but indeed seems to be correct. See [EXIF standard here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131018091152/http://exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF).

Comment: According to the [ExifTool docs](http://web.mit.edu/graphics/src/Image-ExifTool-6.99/html/faq.html#Q4), `FNumber` and `ExposureTime` correspond to the values we're used to working with, and `ApertureValue` and `ShutterSpeedValue` are the APEX values.

Comment: FWIW, my Pentax camera doesn't seem to set the APEX tags at all. My Nexus phone does, however. Both ExifTool and Exiv2 convert `ApertueValue` to f/number for display (in this case, f/2.4), but if I look at the raw values, `Fnumber` is set to 240/100 and `ApertureValue` to 252/100 — the corresponding APEX value. Hmmm. I'm not sure if these tools are making it more or less confusing by converting.