# How do XMP files encode aperture?

Tags: aperture, metadata, xmp

When I open a Lightroom XMP file, I read this odd line (the photo has been taken at f/8.0, all tools agree with that)

```
   exif:ApertureValue="6/1"
```

Apparently, `6/1` means `f/8.0`, but where is this correspondance defined? Is it Lightroom specific? defined by XMP?

Note: It's not only for science's sake, I am currently trying to recover for a hard disk crash where I lost all filenames

Comment: hi, this previous question discuss this:- http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19143/how-can-the-aperture-value-written-in-exif-be-larger-than-the-nominal-limit-of-t

And this provides some background reading
http://dougkerr.net/Pumpkin/articles/APEX.pdf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **Exif:ApertureValue** is stored as an APEX value as mandated by various EXIF standards.

The APEX system is a way to calculate exposure and works using base-2 logarithms.  The use of base-2 means a rise of one in the value equates to a doubling, which we know as `1 stop`; which makes it pretty handy for photographers if they're good with logarithms (which we don't use much nowadays). Do note, however, that 1 stop in aperture means doubling of the **square** of the F-number -- for example, going from f/2.8 to f/4 is 1 stop because 4<sup>2</sup> = 2 * 2.8<sup>2</sup> (approximately).

**To convert from APEX to F-numbers**, use the following equation:

> ApertureValue (Av) = log<sub>2</sub> (F-number)<sup>2</sup> = 2 log<sub>2</sub> (F-number)
>      ⇒ F-number = 2<sup>Av / 2</sup>

**To convert `f/8.0` to it's APEX value `6/1`...**

> `Log2(8) = 3`
>   `3 * 2 = 6` (or `6/1` as a fraction)

**To convert the `6/1` APEX value back to *f*/8...**

> `6/2 = 3`
>   `2^3 = 8` giving us back *f*/8.0

**See also:**

- ExifTool: [Exif Tags](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html)
- APEX—The Additive System of Photographic Exposure ([PDF](http://dougkerr.net/Pumpkin/articles/APEX.pdf)) – Contains tables and equations, but no calculation examples.
- JEITA CP-3451 Exif 2.2 ([PDF](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF)) – Contains conversion equations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. According to [this list](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) **Exif.Photo.ApertureValue** is "*The lens aperture. The unit is the **APEX** value.*" Which is confirmed by [Wikipedia article on APEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system#Use_of_APEX_values_in_Exif). No idea how to make the conversion though.