# What's the difference between aperture value and f-number?

Tags: aperture, f-stop

[image: Image Metadata]

In macOS Finder it says a photo taken at f/2.8 has an aperture value of 3. What is an aperture value, and how is it different from f-stop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the aperture value written in Exif be larger than the nominal limit of the lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19143/how-can-the-aperture-value-written-in-exif-be-larger-than-the-nominal-limit-of-t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Exif standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20131018091152/http://exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) says that:

$$\text{ApertureValue}=2\log_2(\text{FNumber})$$

which is also:

$$\text{ApertureValue}=\frac{2\log(\text{FNumber})}{\log2}$$

There is even a nice conversion table:

| ApertureValue (APEX) | F-Number |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1.4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2.8 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5.6 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 11 |
| 8 | 16 |
| 9 | 22 |
| 10 | 32 |

However, looking at my own photos (EOS 70D), I find that the exposure value and the FNumber are close to each other but not always equal, so this doesn't follow the table below for apertures => f/8. So I wonder if for Canon, these tags wouldn't be:

- F Number: what you (or the auto-exposure) have set the camera to
- Aperture value: actual aperture taking in account actual focal length (that changes with focus....)

Comment: What are you using to view the EXIF info? It may be converting the hex value for the Aperture Value field to f-number (actual as opposed to rounded off setting) rather than to actual AV. Irfanview seems to do this.

Comment: @MichaelC Both Gwenview and Exiftool report the same values. These two items are defined as RATIONAL in the standard and seem to be encoded the same way.

Comment: Considering that they are always the same number for the same f-number regardless of focus position or zoom position for zoom lenses across various different lenses (for example f/3.2 always shows as AV "F 3.22" in irfanview with lenses as varied as the EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II and the EF 50mm f/1.4), I doubt it is doing what your last point suggests. Instead it seems to be showing the theoretical actual figured number to two decimal places for our rounded f-number scale that only uses a single decimal place.

Answer (score 3):

The AV (Aperture Value) is an expression that tells how many stops away from f/1 an aperture is.

Since f/1 is zero distance from f/1, it has an AV of zero (0)
Since f/1.4 is one stop slower than f/1, it has an AV of one (1)
Since f/2 is two stops away from f/1, it has an AV of two (2)
Since f/2.8 is three stops from f/1, its AV is three (3)
... and so on.

For instance, f/16 is eight stops slower than f/1, it has an AV of eight (8).

Apertures faster than f/1 have negative AV. For example, f/0.5 is two stops faster than f/1, and has an AV of -2.